# proof variant of Farkas’ Lemma - Homogeneous Inequalities with Positive Solutions

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

need help to prove the following: (already prove that both can't holds, but I need to show that if (a) doesn't hold then (b) hold)

Let A ∈ Mm×d(R). Prove that exactly one the following holds:

(a) There exists x ∈ $R^d$
such that Ax ≤ 0 and x > 0.

(b) There exists y ∈ $R^m$, satisfying y ≥ 0 and $y^T$A ≩ 0.